# How to make an application go to a web version of a website on android

Tags: android, android-layout, apk, android-resources

I am trying to make an application for android (a browser) and want the option for users to go the web version of the website (when there is no option to switch to the web version), how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebView you can play with settings.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

EDIT:
I also found that

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgent(1);
```

Should work in similiar fashion.